# Select query with "is null"-clause and subselect / left join returns no results

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, left-join

I'm trying, on base of Oracle 12c, to select entries from a DETAIL table which should fulfill two where-constraints:

1. foreign key is in sub-select
2. column is null

The following statement with the sub-select (in-clause) returns no results at all.

```
select *
  from DETAIL
  where (PARENT_ID) in (
    select ID from MASTER where COL1 = 1)
  and COL2 is null;
```

And also the left join returns no results:

```
select d.*
from MASTER m
left join DETAIL d
  on d.PARENT_ID = m.ID
where m.COL1 = 1
  and d.COL2 is null;
```

My table setup contains the following tables:

```
create table MASTER (
  ID NUMBER(19) NOT NULL,
  COL1 NUMBER(19),
  primary key (ID)
);
insert into MASTER ("ID", "COL1") VALUES (1, 1);
insert into MASTER ("ID", "COL1") VALUES (2, 2);
insert into MASTER ("ID", "COL1") VALUES (3, 1);

create table DETAIL (
  ID NUMBER(19) NOT NULL,
  PARENT_ID NUMBER(19),
  COL2 NUMBER(2,0),
  primary key (ID),
  foreign key (PARENT_ID) references MASTER(ID)
);
insert into DETAIL ("ID", "PARENT_ID", "COL2") VALUES (1, 1, 1);
insert into DETAIL ("ID", "PARENT_ID", "COL2") VALUES (2, 2, 1);
insert into DETAIL ("ID", "PARENT_ID", "COL2") VALUES (3, 3, 1);
insert into DETAIL ("ID", "PARENT_ID", "COL2") VALUES (4, 3, 2);
```

I would expect to get more than 0 entries as result on base of the code above.

Any recommandations? Thanks!

Comment: In your sample  all the rows with   parent_id mathc and the matching rows  have not col2  with NULL .. this mean that your LEFT JOIN return ever full result

Comment: "I would expect" Why? When you tell us why, it helps us to explain to you where you have wrong ideas.

Answer (score 1):

In your DETAIL table COL2 always has a value and is thus never NULL. Because of this the `COL2 IS NULL` condition is never satisfied, and your queries return no results.